# Create a Osx Server VPN inside BTMM

Tags: networking, vpn, osx-server, icloud

I've set up BTMM between a group of computers, one of which is a OSX server sitting at home. I know I can use SSH port forwarding to access something inside my network, but is it possible to use my Back to my Mac domain and IPv6 addresses to create a VPN into the whole of my network?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is not a complete possibility....

The BTMM DNS is only available to whom has BTMM services available on their machine. The DNS is not externally available, so it's not something that other's can get access too. With that said, the DNS works for people that have your BTMM account, so you could possibly setup a VPN, and use that to ping the ports.

There are tutorials for BTMM ssh, that's probably your starting point.

http://www.cnet.com/news/how-to-connect-via-ssh-using-iclouds-back-to-my-mac-service/